# how to create meetup event using API

Tags: meetup

I am currently trying to integrate meetup.com API but finding difficulty to do it for creating a event there I has to use group id as a parameter can any one help me to find out a free group id because I want to test my event creation there.

Comment: thanks for your reply but still I am searching for a sandbox to test my Api where I can create group free of cost and to create events there there would be some free testing group of meetup.com should be available did any one know this otherwise I have to create and purchase subscription for creating group in meetup.com

Comment: Visit http://www.meetup.com/Meetup-API-Testing/ click on "Contact" and request post permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation about the API call you're searching for is found [here](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/event/#create).
I think you have to be the creator of a group or have permissions to create events in a certain group for using it's group id in the API call, but I can't test since groups cost money to set up. If you don't have permissions, the API will respond to your call with a 401 HTTP status code.